# Struts 1.3 and data are not loaded in the div

Tags: jsp, jquery, struts, struts-1

Currently I am facing a problem, need to load data in the div tag.

Following code is used

```
function submitDetailsEvent(subevent,value)
{
    $("a").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "circuitDetails.do?euclid="+value+"&event="+subevent,
            async: false,
            success: function(data){
                         alert(data);
                         $("#information").html(data); 
                     },// success
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert("Error: " + (errorThrown ? errorThrown : xhr.status));
                   } 
        }); 
        return false;
    });    
}
```

I call the above function and pass some event value and data value . alert is not even loading my success data. could anyone guide me on this.

Comment: You can place the html code?

Comment: @alditis sorry i didnt unnderstand your question

Comment: result is not getting loaded on single click also

Comment: Maybe you can try the $.post() method to send the data in JSON format: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: i have place my jsp code here http://jsfiddle.net/rEzWH/

Comment: @alditis I am trying using $.post().. jquery method

Comment: @alditis using $.post() data is populating but it is loading in a new page and not on the same page div.

Comment: return false after using the post method. 
$.post("/...", function(data){ ... }); return false;

Answer (score 1):

If you call the function you should remove the click handler:

```
function submitDetailsEvent(subevent,value)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "circuitDetails.do?euclid="+value+"&event="+subevent,
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
                     alert(data);
                     $("#information").html(data); 
                 },// success
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert("Error: " + (errorThrown ? errorThrown : xhr.status));
               } 
    }); 
    return false;

}
```

Then, if you need it, you could bind the call to anchors with:

```
$('a').click(
    function(e){
        value = ...;
        submitDetailsEvent(e, value);
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks it resolved a part of problen but still data is not loaded

Comment: Does `data` contain what you expect? Do you have one -and only one- element in your document with id `information`?

Comment: yes we have only one div tag in our document. yes data is getting loaded but in different page using $.post()

Comment: If the data comes from another domain or protocol you cannot use it directly (it would be XSS). You could try to clone the data and then load the cloned data into your document.

Comment: @Priya Can you post your circuitDetails action available in struts-config.xml file?